# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find HmacSHA1 algorithm

Tags: hadoop

After install hadoop through `brew install hadoop`,i want to start up hadoop,
when run hadoop2.7.2  /start-all.sh on mac,it went wrong,the logs:

```
Swing Hu  19:53:45
16/08/19 19:50:25 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = swinghu (auth:SIMPLE)
16/08/19 19:50:25 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
16/08/19 19:50:25 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
16/08/19 19:50:25 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
16/08/19 19:50:25 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
16/08/19 19:50:25 ERROR namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find HmacSHA1 algorithm.
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager.<init>(SecretManager.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager.<init>(AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.security.token.delegation.DelegationTokenSecretManager.<init>(DelegationTokenSecretManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.createDelegationTokenSecretManager(FSNamesystem.java:6600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
16/08/19 19:50:25 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for acti
```

Answer (score 0):

After two days after,it goes well,it may be i reboot my mac book pro.Strangely